# Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Starting Saturday, Aug 23, 2014, our [weekly genealogy chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat), which just entered its **2nd Year** (born Aug 10, 2013), becomes a **WEEK LONG event!**.

Feel free to drop in and share your thoughts anytime. If you wish, you can [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) for the event beforehand so you get a reminder before it starts.

**Important note:** The Weekly Genealogy Chat occurs [in its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat), not the main room (Roots).

*If you have any topic ideas for sequential weeks, feel free to share them in an answer here - or while you are in the chat with us!*

---

We're reviving the Weekly Chat -- and starting off 2015 by following along with Thomas MacEntee's Genealogy Do-Over:  see **[2015: Year (okay, thirteen weeks) of the Do-Over?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1952/56)**

**The Do-Over will finish up in March, so let's hear your ideas for new weekly chat topics!**

The topics for older chats are below.

- **[Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat, week beginning 27 September 2014 | Uh-oh! These weren't the DNA test results I was expecting!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1883/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat, week beginning 20 September 2014 | Using non-specialist tools for your research](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1879/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat, week beginning 13 September 2014 | Improving the Weekly Chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1877/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 1st Saturday of Month | Monthly Workshop Chat (next on 6th September)](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1840/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat, weeks beginning 23 & 30 August 2014 | Using GIS for Genealogy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/19)**
- **[Genealogy Chat, week of 16 August 2014 | Interpreting Photographs](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1864/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 1st Saturday of Month | Monthly Workshop Chat (next on 6th September)](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1840/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 26 July 2014 | Graduating the Site](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1850/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 19th July 2014 | Stay at Home Genealogy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1849/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 12th July 2014 | Working to the Genealogical Proof Standard](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1848/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 28th June 2014 | Starting Over? Why and When?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1846/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 21st June 2014 | Desktop or Web?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1845/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 14th June | Researching the Female Line](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1843/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 1st Saturday of Month | Monthly Workshop Chat (next on 6th September)](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1840/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 31 May 2014 | Paleography and handwriting](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1837/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 24 May 2014 | What's in a name?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1835/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 17 May | Somebody is wrong on the Internet!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1834/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 10 May 2014 | Ephemera and unofficial sources](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1833/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 3 May 2014 | Advice for getting started](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1832/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 26 April | Geography and Genealogy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1830/104)**
- 19 April 2014: No chat
- **[Genealogy Chat 12 April 2014: Genealogy Search Engines -- The Good, the Bad and the Ugly](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1826/104)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 5 Apr 2014 | Effective Citations](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1825/56)**
- [Our topic for 29 March 2014 will be : **Understanding historical contexts**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1824/56)
- [Our topic for 22 March 2014 will be: **Genealogy Utility Software**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1821/104)
- [Our topic for 15 March 2014 will be: **Work in Progress**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1820/104)
- [Our topic for 21 February 2014 will be **What I wish I'd known when I started**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1809/56)
- [Our topic for 15 February 2014 will be **Tracking down local sources**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/56)
- [Our topic for 8 February 2014 will be **Making Time for Genealogy**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1807/56)
- [Our topic for 1 February 2014 will be **"Essential websites"**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1805/56)
- [Our topic for 25 January 2014 will be **"Clue or red herring?"**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1804/56)
- [Our topic for 18 January 2014 will be **"What's on your bookshelf?"**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1802/56)
- Our topic for 11 January 2014 will be **"Wow records"**
- [Our topic for 4 January 2014 will be **Comparing workflows**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1798/56)
- There will be no official chat topic on 21 December and 28 December 2013.
- [Our topic for 14 December 2013 will be **Mistakes we've made**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1791/56)
- [Our topic for 7 December 2013 will be **Holiday genealogy**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1784/56)
- [Our topic for 30 November 2013 will be **Doing Genealogy on the cheap**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/104)
- [Our topic for 23 November 2013 will be **Getting the most out of the big sites**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1776/104)
- [Our topic for 11/16/2013 will be **engaging relatives or getting older people to share what they have/know**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1775/56)
- [Our topic for 11/9/2013 will be **language barriers**](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/56)
- **[Sharing your work -- tips, tricks, pitfalls and prizes](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1770/56)** will be our topic again for 11/2/2013
- Our topic for 10/26/2013 will be **Sharing your work -- tips, tricks, pitfalls and prizes**
- Our topic for 10/12/2013 will be **ephemera and other sources not of an official nature**
- Our topic for 10/5/2013 will be **Genealogy Travel**.
- Our topic for 8/31/2013 will be **current brick walls and how to break them**.
- Our topic for the first week  (8/10/2013) will be **Genealogy software**.

Comment: If you don't have a favourite timezone checker, http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meeting.html will do the job. 1100 UTC is 12 noon in London, 6AM in Chicago and 9PM in Sydney, for example. Luke, presumably people can turn up without registering? Registration just gets a reminder (and lets you know how many people are thinking of attending...)

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl Precisely. It also gives us a head count on who's coming.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh! I missed the chat! :( Registered for the reminder. Will not miss again :( nuts.

Comment: Almost 1000 users, currently at 999

Comment: I see that some of the chat room events for other sites display a start time: "[time] in your timezone".  Would it help if we translated what "all day" means for different timezones?

Comment: Can we revisit [How helpful will joining my local Genealogical Society be if my family research is in a distant location?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/300/how-helpful-will-joining-my-local-genealogical-society-be-if-my-family-research) as a chat topic?

Answer (score 6):

**[Topic for 2/15/2014]**

Topic for future weekly chat: **How do we track down sources for an area/timeframe that we're interested in?** I'm hoping a chat will help us structure a series of 'canonical posts' about locating sources for different countries.

Stealing shamelessly from https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/754:

> The idea behind Canonical Posts is to take a subject which is often
>   encountered ... and create a post which thoroughly explains that
>   topic. The goal is for these posts to be as useful and
>   easy-to-understand as possible.

Comment: I like the idea, but I don't think it's a good fit for chat. I can't imagine there would be much to talk about other than "What areas are you an expert in? Okay, well you go to that one."

Comment: @justinY, I was thinking the chat would be about how we each track down sources, and that the work to help structure the canonical posts would be done after the event from the transcript (deriving the structure rather than talking about it explicitly.)

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it seems like a waste of chat event because we would just be dumping URLs and stuff. I think a Google Doc or Spreadsheet would be better because it can be organized and be done according to our own time frame.

Comment: I've used similar techniques in brainstorms where URLs aren't even a possibility and they work well -- focus is on process not outputs. But if the consensus is that it won't work for the weekly chat I'll set up a separate chat room for canonical questions the way ELL has done it.

Comment: I could go for a separate chat room; it's much better than trying to fit this into a chat event.

Comment: @JustinY, the focus would still be on 'how we find sources' not 'how we structure the relevant canonical questions'.

Comment: Would the chat be focused on a given area and time period?

Comment: @JustinY In the dedicated chat room? No -- that would be too restricting (especially time period). We might choose to focus on a particular geography for a while (e.g. the States, Australia, or England & Wales) especially if a relevant Canonical Question was active. If we were doing it in the weekly chat, we might make a different judgement.

Comment: The difficulty with the weekly chat, especially at this time of year, is that many people may have holiday and family things on the weekend.  A dedicated chat room might be better.  I would suggest focusing on either time or place, or discussing local resources vs. national archives, or some topic which is focused enough but not too much.

Answer (score 4):

### **Desktop vs Web [Topic for 21st June 2014]**

If you still use desktop tree software, why? What do popular web products lack that your desktop product offers?

Comment: That'll be a quick conversation, Justin :))  More like; what's wrong with web-based trees....

Comment: It could be rolled into the first topic, Genealogy Software.

Comment: Desktop: Most people want their data in under their own control. Web: You don't know if its really yours or not.

Comment: Web: the best way I know of losing control of your data (if it's editable).

Comment: Web: if my ISP screws up, I don't have access to my work.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some things that come to mind.

1. I've seen several questions where the mods have responded that they aren't really a good SE question -- might some of these questions be good topics for chats? E.g. [How can we gain confidence in different types of records?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/117/how-can-we-gain-confidence-in-different-types-of-records/1488#1488)
2. Good research practice, where we confess mistakes we have made when starting out. Sort of like What Not To Wear, only for Genealogy. **[Topic for 12/14/2013]**
3. I'm in the midst of reviewing my prior research, and would enjoy discussing workflow and effective ways to do a review with others.  Would this be a good chat topic?  What are the advantages of reviewing all the source material for one person as a group?  Of transcribing all the census records for the same town in a particular census year, and examining them as a group?  Of looking at a set of siblings all at once? And so on. **[Topic for 1/4/2014]**
4. Is that odd bit of information a discrepancy, or an important clue?  (used as a launching point for sharing case histories)  When do you decide to let it go? **[Topic for 1/25/2014]**
5. Netiquette.  Another user on Ancestry has a person who matches someone on my tree, and the sources attached to that person are from Mars (their sources disagree with one another ).  It looks like push-button-itis. Do I contact them, and if so, what do I say?  How do you talk with tact about the fact that two trees wildly disagree and avoid barging in and saying, "look here, you're all wrong".  Or is it better to just ignore them, and let them come to you? [**Topic for 17 May 2014**]

P.S. Copied from chat:

> Martin Sojka Jul 15, 1:16 I wish we had a proper genealogy-specific
>   search engine. Something which on a name would find just the relevant
>   records, both original and on sites like MyHeritage, FamilySearch and
>   WikiTree.

What a proper genealogy-specific search engine might look like -- or what a proper search engine for a service like Ancestry, FindMyPast, WorldVitalRecords, etc. might look like -- that could fill many chats.  Many.  Well, I could fill them, anyway.  **[Topic for 12 April 2014]**

Edited to add: I'm new to SE, so feel free to point me to any guidelines.

Comment: I like "Mistakes we made" idea, and also comparing workflows. Well, actually, I like them all.

Comment: Note ColeValleyGirl's comment was made before I added #5.

Comment: I like #5 as well. A lot... Let me tell you about the time when... Nope. I'll save it for the chat!

Comment: Is it 'best practice' to keep editing one's own answer? Because I keep thinking of things, like "do you research relatives who have left the family because of divorce?"  Why can't I come up with good answerable questions instead? <FX: bangs head on desk>

Comment: editing your own answer is preferred to creating new ones. The only risk is that it will become 'Community Wiki' (i.e. belonging to everyone and not to you) if you edit it too much. Let me do a quick training course :) and I'll see if I can change this back to your ownership!

Comment: For this particular case (coming up with new chat topics) it might be more practical to break the established convention and ask people to post each topic as a separate answer. Unless the SE setup would punish the user.

Comment: True; on Meta it's not so important -- on the main site however, where there is (we hope) a 'best' answer, we'd encourage editing.

Comment: I don't like making extra work for the mods and just want to do what's best for everyone.

Comment: It's not really extra work, whichever you do on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

### [Topic for 10/5/2013]

I have an idea for a chat topic... **Genealogy Travel**.
People learn from people. It'd be interesting to hear how people set themselves up to succeed on a research trip. Do they start planning 6 months in advance? Do they tack on research to a trip that is mainly for other purposes such as business? How would that affect planning, how do you know what to search for first and where to search for it? ...What is more important, getting a hotel with a great TripAdvisor rating, or one that is across the street from the archives? I'd like some recommendations that come through hard-won experience.
I also think that it would be fun to hear some horror stories or celebration stories. "The best genealogy trip I ever had was..., because..." or "the one thing I will always bring with me is..., because once this happened to me..." This is the kind of thing that you can't do in a SE question. Maybe there are things that people always do now, because they learned the hard way on a trip once.
I think that travelling can be intimidating. I also think that phoning an archives or making contact with an historical society can be intimidating... Do successful genealogists get over this fear and make a bunch of calls before they go?
The topic could be looked at from many angles.

Comment: Also related to this, a sort of follow-up to the 'save money' chat:  how do you prioritize the money that you spend on genealogy?  It occurs to me that the type of preparation one would do for a research trip would also be useful for deciding what films to order from the FHL, etc.  How do you maximize the amount of value you get from the money you spend?

Comment: "How do you maximize the amount of value..." Seriously, I think that this comes down to planning, planning, planning. From everything like where your hotel is located in relation to the records, knowing what the process for ordering/requesting materials or gaining access to a historic site is, etc. etc. Can you believe that I was in Edinburgh and headed off bright and early Sunday morning for a day of research in the Records Office... only to discover that it is only open weekdays :( Bad planning on my part. I should have figured that out in Canada. It would have saved me an entire day.

Answer (score 2):

### What's on your Genealogy Bookshelf? **[Topic for 1/18/2014]**

What books do you find invaluable in your research -- perhaps 'how to' books about methodology, or reference works specific to a country or topic.

We don't do book recommendations in the Q&A section, but we can do them in chat!

Answer (score 2):

#### Stay-at-home Genealogy [Topic for 19th July 2014]

Not all of us have the budget for genealogy travel. Making the most of the internet and local research avenues is important. Share and receive tips on how to conduct thorough research locally and efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Would anyone else be interested in a once-a-month brainstorming session?

- The site just went through self-evaluation.  For the questions which were marked "needs improvement" could chat be a vehicle by which we all focus on the same question at once and write up a better answer as a Community Wiki?
- One of my local sewing shops offers a class where people can bring in their unfinished projects and work on them, and get advice from a teacher (and presumably other classmates).  I'm having a problem figuring out exactly which microfilm I need to order for a couple of records I want to look at. This seems too persnickety for a regular G&FH.SE question, but I would appreciate having someone to look over the FHL Catalog record with me.  Is this something for which chat would be better?

Comment: Great ideas, Jan.

Comment: Would it be worthwhile to have MetaChats (about topics that belong in Meta)?

Comment: Another good idea, as long as the topics are significant enough (or a bunch can be gathered together, perhaps)

Comment: The chat topic I need today: How to Stay Focused While Using Ancestry.com.

Answer (score 2):

### How can we graduate Beta sooner rather than later? [Topic for 26 July 2014]

We are fast approaching our 600th day as a Beta site of Stack Exchange.

Our **[Beta Site Stats Summary](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history)** is available to review so let's brainstorm any ideas you may have to help put us further along the road to graduation.

Our visits per day (492) is not far off the 500 per day that would see us lift from red to amber but our questions per day (1.3) is well below the 5 per day that would be needed to do likewise for that measure.

Do we just need to post/encourage more questions in order for everything else to flow?
Are we getting the right kind of questions to encourage more posting of others?
Are we getting the right kind of answers to encourage more posting of questions?

Is a focus on more questions the right approach or would you like to suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

### **Working towards the Genealogical Proof Standard**

[Topic for 12 July 2014]

The [Board for Certification of Genealogists](http://www.bcgcertification.org/resources/standard.html) says:

> Proof is a fundamental concept in genealogy. In order to merit
>   confidence, each conclusion about an ancestor must have sufficient
>   credibility to be accepted as "proved." Acceptable conclusions,
>   therefore, meet the Genealogical Proof Standard (GPS). The GPS
>   consists of five elements:
>
> - a reasonably exhaustive search;
> - complete and accurate source citations;
> - analysis and correlation of the collected information;
> - resolution of any conflicting evidence; and
> - a soundly reasoned, coherently written conclusion.

In your day-to-day research into genealogy and family history do you apply this strictly, work towards it when possible, or perhaps do it already without realising that way of working had a name?

Answer (score 2):

### What tools (that aren't specialist family history tools) are useful in conducting or publishing your research? [Topic for week of 20 Sep 2014]

I've seen mention of [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) and [Outwit](http://www.outwit.com/) -- have you found these useful? And — thinking outside the genealogy box — what else have you used that might be useful to others?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add the timestamp -- this is the topic for the upcoming Weekly Genealogy Chat.  Hope you can drop in!

Answer (score 1):

More ideas:

- What's on your To Do List?
- What kind of records on your Research Map are marked "Here Be Dragons"?
- What are some of your "wow" records (that you were really excited to find)? **[Topic for 1/11/2014]**
- If I Were Dictator:  things I would change about online genealogy sites
- What's in your library? (essential Genealogy Books) <== Community Wiki Bait **[Topic for 1/18/2014]**
- Essential Websites <== Community Wiki Bait **[Topic for 2/1/2014]**

I'd also like to see a series of hosted discussions (not necessarily part of the weekly chat) on technical topics.  For instance -- last weekend while I was hanging out in chat and working in another window, I did a Google search on persona records and ended up reading a lot of blog posts and forum discussions written by participants here on G&FH.se.  Could we do something like a Reddit Ask Me Anything where a volunteer makes him/herself available for questions?  The software developers could sound off about their software, I could talk about how my linguistics experience has informed my family history research, and so on.  Obviously a person couldn't hang out the entire 24 hour chat window but they could be there for a few hours, and people could leave questions which could be answered later as time permitted.  I think the Reddit AMAs are a couple of hours.

Comment: Does SE ever have chats with invited guests?  Might that be a way to draw experts to SE?  Establish a separate chat room where users can leave questions in advance, maybe.

Comment: Yes. I know other sites, such as Blender.SE have done it in the past. Do you have someone in mind?

Comment: We might start with the software developers already here.  I'd love to talk more with Tom Wetmore about persona records.  We have ColeValleyGirl who is beta testing GenQuiry.  Perhaps some of the other Family Historian UG people would be willing to come over and talk about writing FH plugins.  Once we have been doing it for a while and have a track record of people actually showing up with good questions, it might be easier to invite bigger names. But we need to work out the bugs closer to home first. You don't want the scenario where a guest shows up and no one else comes.

Answer (score 1):

### Making Time for Genealogy **[Topic for 2/8/2014]**

For most of us, genealogy is a hobby not a profession. How do you we fit it in among all the other demands on our time -- our families, our jobs, our communities, our other interests. We can share tips and tricks for making time, and for using that time effectively.

Answer (score 1):

### Starting Over? Why and When? [Topic for 28 June 2014]

If you spend any time in the genealogy/family history corners of the Internet, sooner or later you'll encounter somebody '***Starting over***' -- re-tracing and re-recording their research.

When is this a good idea, and why? Or are there better ways to deal with the perceived problems of (among others) poor citations, lack of consistency in using the features of your software, realising that for the last 10 years you've been researching completely the wrong line....

Comment: "realising that for the last 10 years you've been researching completely the wrong line...." Ouch. That has got to hurt.

Comment: @AmericanLuke It didn't actually happen to me -- or rather, only for 1 year not 10 -- but I've heard of people to whom it did happen

Comment: I recently re-read one of my 'how to' books where the author confessed she had traced an incorrect line for _decades_.

Answer (score 1):

### Tracing the Female Lines [Topic for 14th June 2014]

There are unique challenges to tracing the female line, at least in Western cultures.  Name changes (sometimes many of them) every generation. Relative lack of property records. Not named in many birth and marriage registers.

What are the tips and tricks you've used when tracing the women in your ancestry? And what are the stand-out stories you've leanred about those women?

Answer (score 1):

### Using Geography Tools to research and display our Family History

Displaying where our ancestors lived, and how they moved about, can be surprisingly revealing.  We can talk about using tools such as ArcGIS (or others)  to display our ancestor's stories. And about the pitfalls of encoding geographical info within our genealogy databases.

Answer (score 1):

- After [Gae­no­vium 2014](http://www.gaenovium.com/) (which is coming up in October 2014) please can we have a post-conference chat with speakers @ACProctor and @lkessler and any other developers who attended the conference?
- For a more general topic, we could have a chat on conferences in general -- which ones have we attended, were they helpful, which conferences put sessions online for viewing afterwards or make their syllabuses available for download, and so on.
- Another related topic: what we do for 'ongoing education' either formal or informal.  What blogs / Hangouts / newsletters / etc. are useful to keep up with for current events and so on.
- Beyond the Person: Using geographically-based websites e.g [Curious Fox](http://www.curiousfox.com/).
- Beyond the Person: Using record-based websites e.g. [Lost Cousins](http://www.lostcousins.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Re: the question: [Personal family history website with rich media support?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/personal-family-history-website-with-rich-media-support)

Discussing the pros/cons of using the various existing services for social connections and genealogy collaboration (e.g. Facebook, Google Groups) might be a good topic for a weekly chat that could be mined for a Community Wiki Q/A.

Answer (score 1):

### **Improving the Weekly Chat [Topic for week beginning 13 September 2014]**

Posting a new answer here to call attention to the Meta Q [Improving The Weekly Chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/improving-the-weekly-chat). If you haven't seen that Q and the various As, please take a look and post your thoughts.

My current idea for next week's chat (tongue-in-cheek, to be sure) is to find a better name for the Weekly Chat room.