# Genealogy Chat 11/2/2013 | Sharing your work

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 11/2/2013 will be **Sharing your work -- tips, tricks, pitfalls and prizes**.

> We all want to share our work. Sometimes for the kudos, sometimes for the chance of making contact with those who are researching the same ancestors. What methods of sharing your work have been most successful for you? Is it always an unalloyed benefit, or are there pitfalls to be aware of?
>
> Come and talk about your experiences of sharing your work -- good and bad. What would you do differently if you were starting today? How much value does your own website bring? What about familysearch, geni, ancestry and other 'big trees'?

[Here is the transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/conversation/sharing-your-work-chat-11-2-2013) of this chat.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!