# Genealogy Chat 11/9/13 | Language Barriers

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our chat topic of the week for 11/9/2013 will be **language barriers**.

> Fluency in multiple languages is very handy in genealogical research. Some of us can speak multiple languages and others just have their primary language and Google translate.
>
> Come and chat about your experiences with different languages and language barriers. What do you do when you need to translate a foreign language? What's your weirdest experience with other languages?

Here is a [transcript of the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/conversation/language-barriers-chat-11-9-2013).

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!