# Genealogy Chat 11/16/13 | Engaging relatives

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our chat topic of the week for 11/9/2013 will be **engaging relatives or getting older people to share what they have/know**.

> Almost every genealogy starts with asking the older generation. Some relatives openly share their past and others just aren't comfortable sharing or don't remember much about their past.
>
> Come and chat about your experiences engaging relatives and getting to know their histories. Have you had any successes gleaning information? What tips would you give to someone else trying to collect information from older relatives?

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!