# Genealogy Chat 23 November 2013 : Getting the most out of the big sites

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 23 November 2013  will be : **Getting the most out of the big genealogy sites.**

Many of us use one or more of the big genealogy sites, such as Ancestry, findmypast, Familysearch etc.

Come and talk about your experiences of using those sites -- good and bad. What search techniques work best on each site? How do you make best use of the facilities for documenting your tree? For making contact with others? What tips and techniques would you like to share with others?

The chat will occur in its own room all Saturday long. Be sure to register yourself to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to Weekly genealogy chat topics! and they might be used in an upcoming week!