# Genealogy Chat 30 November 2013: Doing Genealogy on the cheap

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 30 November 2013 will be : **Doing Genealogy on the cheap.**

Tracking down our ancestors can be expensive -- paying for website subscriptions, research trips, copies of documents, the software we use...

Come and share your ideas for controlling the costs -- such as good free record sources for the countries you ancestors came from, or useful software that doesn't cost the earth. Or do you believe that you get what you pay for, and it isn't possible to do effective genealogy on the cheap?

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!

Comment: How does one register to get reminders for the weekly chat?

Comment: @JanMurphy You can register yourself [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) for reminders.

Comment: Thanks, I found it and registered.

Answer (score 1):

I keep sliding off-topic in today's chat -- sorry!

One topic for a future chat might be: Good research practice, where we confess mistakes we have made when starting out.  Sort of like What Not To Wear, only for Genealogy.

Comment: That's a great idea! Could you post it [here](http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) so we can find it easily? Thanks!