# Genealogy Chat 7 Dec 2013: Holiday Genealogy

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 7 December 2013 will be : **Holiday Genealogy.**

Christmas is right around the corner and for many of us, that means family gatherings. As genealogists, relatives are an important source of information and family history.

Come and share your ideas for this holiday season. What do you plan to do with your genealogy this year? Whatever you'll be doing, come and chat about your plans for this holiday season and your past experiences.

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!