# Genealogy Chat 14 Dec 2013: Mistakes we've made

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 14 December 2013 will be : **Mistakes we've made**, [suggested by Jan Murphy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1782/56).

We've all made mistakes and learned lessons the long way around. They're not all that fun at the time, but can be important stepping-stones as genealogists and developing good practices for researching.

As Jan put it, it's the chat "where we confess mistakes we have made when starting out. Sort of like *What Not To Wear*, only for Genealogy." *0.o* . Anyway, come, chat about the mistakes we've all made, and learn how to avoid mistakes others have made and improve your practices!

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!