# Genealogy Chat 4 Jan 2014: Comparing workflows

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 4 January 2013 will be: **Comparing Workflows**, [suggested by Jan Murphy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1782/56).

> "I'm in the midst of reviewing my prior research, and would enjoy discussing workflow and effective ways to do a review with others.... What are the advantages of reviewing all the source material for one person as a group? Of transcribing all the census records for the same town in a particular census year, and examining them as a group? Of looking at a set of siblings all at once? And so on."
>
> <sup>-Jan Murphy</sup>

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!