# Genealogy Chat 18 Jan 2017: What's on your bookshelf?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 18 January 2017 will be: **What's on your bookshelf?**, suggested by [ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1796/56) and [Jan Murphy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1794/56).

> "What books do you find invaluable in your research -- perhaps 'how to' books about methodology, or reference works specific to a country or topic.
>
> We don't do book recommendations in the Q&A section, but we can do them in chat!"
>
> <sup>-ColeValleyGirl</sup>

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!