# Genealogy Chat 25 Jan 2014: Clue or red herring?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 25 January 2013 will be: **Clue or red herring?**, suggested by [Jan Murphy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1782/56).

> "Is that odd bit of information a discrepancy, or an important clue? (used as a launching point for sharing case histories) When do you decide to let it go?"
>
> <sup>-Jan Murphy</sup>

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!