# Genealogy Chat 1 Feb 2014: Essential websites

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 1 February 2013 will be: **Essential Websites**, suggested by [Jan Murphy](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1794/56).

I have a long list of bookmarked web-pages that come in handy often. A good source of places to turn to when stuck is invaluable. Come and share websites essential to your work and find some more  as well.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!