# Genealogy Chat 8 Feb 2014: Making Time for Genealogy

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 8 February 2013 will be: **Making time for genealogy**, suggested by [ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1803/56).

> "For most of us, genealogy is a hobby not a profession. How do you we fit it in among all the other demands on our time -- our families, our jobs, our communities, our other interests. We can share tips and tricks for making time, and for using that time effectively."
>
> <sup>-ColeValleyGirl</sup>

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!