# Genealogy Chat 15 Feb 2014: Tracking down local sources

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 15 February 2013 will be: **Tracking down local sources**, suggested by [ColeValleyGirl](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1751/56).

---

**[Transcript of this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/conversation/tracking-down-local-sources-chat-2-15-2014)**

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!