# Genealogy Chat 21 Feb 2014: What I wish I'd known when I started

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 21 February 2013 will be: **What I wish I'd known when I started**, suggested by ColeValleyGirl.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!