# Genealogy Chat 15 March 2014: Work In Progress

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 15 March 2014 will be: Work in Progress.  Come and talk about the lines you're currently researching, and your progress and successes or brick walls.  Or about the genealogy software you're developing. Or anything else you're working on that is related to Genealogy and Family History.

The chat will occur in its own room all Saturday long. Be sure to register yourself to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to Weekly genealogy chat topics! and they might be used in an upcoming week!