# Genealogy Chat 22 March 2014: Genealogy Utility Software

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for 22 March 2014 will be: Genealogy Utility Software. We all have programmes and/or websites that we use to record our family trees (such as Family Historian, FTM or FamilySearch), and websites we find invaluable for providing access to records (such as FamilySearch or Ancestry). This isn't about those, but instead about utilities, or helper programmes, or plug-ins or gramplets... Whatever you call them, they're the tools we find invaluable while doing our research. Come and talk about the tools you use, and those you wish existed but haven't found yet.

The chat will occur in its own room all Saturday long. Be sure to register yourself to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to Weekly genealogy chat topics! and they might be used in an upcoming week!