# Genealogy Chat 29 Mar 2014 | Understanding Historical Contexts

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for March 29, 2014 will be: **Understanding historical contexts**.

Historical context not only helps us hunt down those unique clues, but it also gives us a fuller picture of who we're researching. I like to call it the fun side of genealogy. Come hop on in next Saturday as we explore the topic.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!