# Genealogy Chat 12 April 2014: Genealogy Search Engines -- The Good, the Bad and the Ugly

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for Apr. 12, 2014 will be: **Genealogy Search Engines**.

We all use online search engines to support our genealogy habit -- be they the search engines within the big sites such as Ancestry, Findmypast and FamilySearch; specialised genealogy search engines such as Mocavo; or general search engines such as Google.

What makes a good search engine for our purposes? And how do you get the best out of the ones that are available to us?

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!