# Genealogy Chat 26 April | Geography and Genealogy

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

There will be no scheduled Genealogy chat on 19 Apr 2014.

On 26 April, our topic will be **Geography and Genealogy**.

At some time we've all had cause to wonder things like:

- Where is this place that my ancestor gave as her birthplace? And what is it called today?
- How did my ancestors travel from X to Y? How long would it have taken?
- Was it really feasible that my ancestor would have met and married a woman who lived Z miles away?

Come and chat about how geography affected our ancestors lives, and how an understanding of that geography can help our research.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!