# Genealogy Chat 3 May 2014 | Advice for getting started

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Our topic of the week for this Saturday (May 3, 2014) will be advice on getting started. This is not only for new genealogists, but also for seasoned pro's to give some tips they find handy. So, whether you're new to genealogy, starting over, or have some good tips up your sleeve, come on over to chat this Saturday!

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!