# Genealogy Chat 10 May 2014 | Ephemera and unofficial sources

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

[A while back in October](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9987/2013/10/12), IIRC, this was the topic for the chat and there were some pretty interesting stories I heard about. Unofficial sources often contain the most interesting and unique tidbits about your ancestor's lives. Come join us Saturday as we discuss this unique aspect of Family History!

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!