# Genealogy Chat 17 May | Somebody is wrong on the Internet!

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

You've put your heart and soul into researching your ancestors, and made the fruits of your labours available on the Internet. And somebody has taken all your hard work and added it to their tree without attribution. Or else, they've published their own tree that's just plain wrong and they won't listen to your corrections. What do you do?

The Internet poses some unique challenges for collaboration. What's the best netiquette in situations such as these? How do you approach total strangers and tell them they've got their conclusions wrong? Or ask them to acknowledge all your hard work? And what do you do if they won't?

For those of you who haven't come across it before, the reference is from: [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/386/).

Come and discuss these dilemmas on Saturday, or any other aspect of sharing your work on the 'net.

Come join us Saturday as we discuss this unique aspect of Family History!

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!

Comment: Favorited because of the reference to xkcd.