# Genealogy Chat 24 May 2014 | What's in a name?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Names are fundamental in Family History research, but they can be tricky things! There are ancestors who acquire or lose names on their journey through life, or change them completely. There are different ways of spelling the same name in different languages (or even the same language). There are nicknames, and pet names. There are different conventions for passing names on to children, different naming systems in different countries... the complexities associated with names are endless.

Come and talk on Saturday about your challenges and successes in tracking down your ancestor's problem names, and share the tips and techniques that have helped you.---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!