# Genealogy Chat 31 May 2014 | Paleography and handwriting

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

You've finally found what promises to be the long-evasive record that holds the information you've been hunting down for months. And the handwriting is indecipherable. The enumerator must have failed the first grade the handwriting is so sloppy. Now you're analyzing every dot and curve for the slightest clue as to what the record says.

Come and talk on Saturday about your challenges and successes in deciphering singularly sloppy handwriting, and share the tips and techniques that have helped you.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!