# Genealogy Chat 14th June | Researching the Female Line

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

There are unique challenges to tracing the female line, at least in Western cultures. Name changes (sometimes many of them) every generation. Relative lack of property records. Not named in many birth and marriage registers.

Comae and share the tips and tricks you've used when tracing the women in your ancestry. And the stand-out stories you've learned about those women.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!

Comment: I'm really looking forward to this topic.  When I first started out, I found many records which gave the names of aunts and their nieces and nephews.  The combination of the birth surnames for the unmarried children and the married surnames of the older women was crucial in demonstrating that yes, all these scattered records really did belong to the same family.