# Genealogy Chat 21st June 2014 | Desktop or Web?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

If you still use desktop tree software, why? What do popular web products lack that your desktop product offers? Conversely, what are the drawback of using those popular web products? Are you worried about losing a lifetime's work? Or about others using it or changing it without your permission? Using killer features in your desktop product? Can't imagine why anyone needs anything except a single shared tree?

Come and discuss the pros and cons of maintaining your family tree in desktop software and/or the web, or both.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!