# Genealogy Chat 28th June 2014 | Starting Over? Why and When?

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

If you spend any time in the genealogy/family history corners of the Internet, sooner or later you'll encounter somebody 'Starting over' -- re-tracing and re-recording their research.

When is this a good idea, and why? Or are there better ways to deal with the perceived problems of (among others) poor citations, lack of consistency in using the features of your software, realising that for the last 10 years you've been researching completely the wrong line....

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!