# Genealogy Chat 12th July 2014 | Working to the Genealogical Proof Standard

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

In genealogy circles in the US, you'll often find somebody who is 'working to the Genealogical Proof Standard' (GPS) or at least working towards it.

What is the GPS? Why does it matter? Is it applicable outside the US, or are there equivalent or better standards? How can you learn about it and apply it in your own research?

Come and discuss the GPS and other standards for genealogy/family history research.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!