# Genealogy Chat week of 7 Aug 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: resolution of any conflicting evidence

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

In [Genealogy Chat 12th July 2014 | Working to the Genealogical Proof Standard](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1848/1006), ColeValleyGirl asked:

> What is the [Genealogical Proof Standard](http://www.bcgcertification.org/resources/standard.html)? Why does it matter? Is it applicable outside the US,
>   or are there equivalent or better standards? How can you learn about
>   it and apply it in your own research?

For our chats in July and August, let's discuss the elements of the GPS and how that relates to our own research, and how writing a focused, solvable question for G&FH.SE can help you.

For the week of 7 Aug 2015, let's talk about resolution of any conflicting evidence. Why is this needed? How do you keep track of the conflicts in the records you've collected?  How do you puzzle out why the records might not agree?

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!