# Genealogy Chat 19th July 2014 | Stay at Home Genealogy

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Not all of us have the budget for genealogy travel, so making the most of the internet and local research avenues is important. Share and receive tips on how to conduct thorough research locally and efficiently.

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!