# Genealogy Chat 26 July 2014 | Graduating the Site

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, graduation

We are fast approaching our 650th day as a Beta site of Stack Exchange.

Our **[Beta Site Stats Summary](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history)** is available to review so let's brainstorm any ideas you may have to help put us further along the road to graduation.  Note that these are not used alone to decide that we have reached "critical mass" but can give us some idea of how our site maturation may be perceived.

Our visits per day (504 on 22 Jul 2014) is borderline with the 500 per day that toggles us from red to amber status (on that one measure) but our questions per day (1.3) is well below the 5 per day that would be needed to do likewise.  On the other three measures we are doing OK (amber) to Excellent (green) so there's plenty of reason for us to be optimistic and proud of how far we have come!

But to graduate ...

- Do we just need to post/encourage more questions in order for everything else to flow?
- Are we getting the right kind of questions to encourage more posting of others?
- Are we getting the right kind of answers to encourage more posting of questions?
- Is a focus on more questions the right approach or would you like to suggest alternatives?
- Perhaps you have ideas on how we can "spread the word" about G&FH SE?
- Maybe there are reasons that prevent people from asking/answering questions that you would like to chat about?

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all Saturday long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!

Comment: @PolyGeo The boilerplate links for the original chat (directing the user to the chat room, and suggesting that users register for reminders) are 1) broken and 2) no longer relevant since we aren't doing weekly chats.  Since link #1 is the only reference, the "chat takes place in its own room" link sends the user to Area 51. I've edited to fix this, but I don't see the point in reviving a Q for an old chat unless you want to propose we revisit it.

Comment: @JanMurphy I see no point revisiting this or starting a new chat until new graduation criteria are known.

Comment: @JanMurphy it only got 'revived' because PolyGeo went on one his regular retagging crusades.