# Genealogy Chat, week of 16 August 2014 | Interpreting Photographs

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Photographs are a different kind of record. I know that I often don't give them much attention. However, they can offer quite valuable information. Not only specific items in the photograph, but also, why was the photograph taken? Come join the chat this week starting Saturday, August 16. **The chat will continue all week so everyone can join in until a new topic starts on August 23.** (See "[Improving the weekly chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/56)" for more details).

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) Saturday through the next Friday. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!