# Genealogy Chat, weeks beginning 23 & 30 August 2014 | Using GIS for Genealogy

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Where our ancestors were born, married and died, (and when, of course), helps us to better understand the events they were or may have been part of.  A Geographical Information System (GIS) is a tool for understanding place and the relationships between places.  Software such as ArcGIS and other tools can be used to display and analyse our ancestors history spatially.  For example, does it make geographic sense that one brother was born 200 miles away from his four younger and three older siblings 200 years ago?

Come join the chat which started Saturday, August 23 and is continuing for another week from Saturday, August 30.

**The chat will continue all week so everyone can join in until a new topic starts on September 6.**

(See "[Improving the weekly chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/56)" for more details).

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) Saturday through the next Friday. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!