# Genealogy Chat, week beginning 13 September 2014 | Improving the Weekly Chat

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Drawing from an existing Meta Q&A on [Improving the weekly chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/improving-the-weekly-chat), this week's chat will be to discuss ideas for doing just that!

> For those who aren't aware, we currently hold a chat in a [dedicated
>   chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) every Saturday about [a different genealogical topic
>   each time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-). It's really great to hop in every week when I can and
>   discuss these topics with fellow genealogists and Stack Exchangians.
>
> After a lot of chats, some things have been plain awesome and others
>   stand out as needing improvement.
>
> - Saturdays aren't always for everyone to make. I know at least, for myself, I have to work Saturdays a lot, so I can't join as often as
>     I'd like. Others have mentioned similar problems. Should we expand the
>     chat to week long (with a new topic every Saturday)?
> - Another aspect up for discussion is where we should hold the chat? There is not much chat happening in our main room, [Roots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6003/roots). Perhaps
>     we are diluting interest by having two separate rooms. Should we merge
>     the two and hold our chats in the main room or keep there own room?
>
> What else can we do to improve this chat and make it as accessible and
>   useful as possible?

Come join the chat which starts Saturday, September 13.

**The chat will continue all week so everyone can join in until a new topic (probably) starts on September 20.**

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) Saturday through the next Friday. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!