# Genealogy Chat, week beginning 20 September 2014 | Using non-specialist tools for your research

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Suggested by @ColeValleyGirl:

**[What tools (that aren't specialist family history tools) are useful in conducting or publishing your research?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1750/weekly-genealogy-chat-topics-now-a-week-long-event/1858#1858)**

> I've seen mention of [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) and [Outwit](http://www.outwit.com/) -- have you found
>   these useful? And -- thinking outside the genealogy box --
>   what else have you used that might be useful to others?

**The chat will continue all week so everyone can join in until a new topic (probably) starts on September 27.**

---

The chat will occur in [its own room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) Saturday through the next Friday. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!