# Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Do you find yourself asking questions that have multiple questions in them?  Do you have a problem you're working on, but you aren't quite sure *what* questions you need to ask?  Would you like someone else to run an eye over your prior research and make suggestions for your research plan, and work out ideas for how you could write a better question?

It's often easier to see the way out when we look at someone else's problem  instead of our own.  So bring your work-in-progress to the monthly Workshop in the Weekly Genealogy Chat room, and give and get some advice on how to turn that "I don't know where to go next" feeling into a **specific, answerable question**.

The chat will occur in [the Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long the first week of each month. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!