# The Genealogy Conference: topics for focused chats

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, chat

As proposed in [Improving the Weekly Chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1853/improving-the-weekly-chat/1855#1855), we'd like to try something new with the Weekly Genealogy Chat room, which we've re-named as **The Conference Room**. It appears in the list of chat rooms as [Genealogy Conference](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference).

1. Pick a topic you'd like to chat about.
2. Post a question here in Meta announcing your topic, and when you'll be available to chat about it.  It's probably best to include your local date and time so that we can include a universal time conversion to it.
3. Alert one of the moderators (via a flag of type Other) so we can tag your question [featured](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) so it will show up in the featured box on the right hand side of the page.
4. We'll open the room in advance so people who can't make it can leave comments for you before your start time.
5. Your question will be listed here, as we've done for the Weekly Chats.

If no on-topic chat is running at the moment, users can also use the Conference Room to workshop a problem that they need help with, but don't quite know yet what the right question is to ask.  If you end up solving the problem in the process, don't forget to write up a self-answered question so others can benefit from your research.

If you have suggestions on how we can refine or improve this idea, (including a better name for the room) please post answers below. Thanks!

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference) all week long. You can [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week if you like.

---

- ??? **YOUR IDEA HERE**
- 13 Dec 2017 to end of WinterBash: #WinterBash2017 chat
- [Improving the Weekly Chat, 2017 edition](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3304/1006) | week of 17 Nov 2017
- Using Population Statistics to supplement your genealogy research | week of 10 Nov 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | Monthly Workshop | week of 3 Nov 2017
- Using Archives for your research | week of 27 Oct 2017
- What I learned at FamilySearch's US and Canada Conference | week of 20 Oct 2017
- French-Canadian Research | week of 13 Oct 2017
- Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop | week of 6 Oct 2017
- Land and Property Records | week of 29 Sep 2017
- Using records as pointers to other records | week of 22 Sep 2017
- Resolving conflicting information | week of 15 Sep 2017
- Using Archives' catalog descriptions in your research | week of 8 Sep 2017
- Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop | week of 1 Sep 2017
- What's in your (software) toolkit? | week of 25 Aug 2017
- Using DNA results as part of your research | week of 18 Aug 2017
- Burial Records and Memorial Inscriptions | week of 11 Aug 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 4 Aug 2017
- Using City Directories and Trade Directories for your research | week of 28 July 2017
- Continuing Education | week of 21 July 2017
- Using Scrivener for Family History Research | week of 14 July 2017
- Finding aids and research guides | week of 7 July 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 30 Jun 2017
- Using Online Special Collections for genealogy | week of 23 Jun 2017
- Chasing online records into the rabbit hole | week of 16 Jun 2017
- What I Learned at SCGS Jamboree 2017 | week of 9 Jun 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 2 Jun 2017
- Memorial Inscriptions and Cemetery websites | week of 26 May
- More Bang for Your Buck | week of 19 May
- Learning from Conferences | week of 12 May
- Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop | week of May 5 2017
- in honor of Anzac Day -- finding and interpreting military records | week of 28 Apr 2017
- Strategies for sorting out same-name people | week of 21 April 2017
- Genealogy education | week of 14 April 2017
- Resources for WWI military records | week of 7 April 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 31 Mar 2017
- Putting Yourself out there: Incorporating DNA into your research | week of 24 Mar 2017
- Getting started with Irish Records | week of 17 March 2017
- [Weekly chat: writing things down -- research plans, journals, and logs | week of 10 Mar 2017](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3222/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) and Monthly Topic Challenge | week of 3 Feb 2017
- Prompts: help or hindrance? | week of 24 Feb 2017
- Maps maps maps Glorious Maps | week of 17 Feb 2017
- What I Learned at RootsTech2017 | week of 10 Feb 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 3 Feb 2017
- [Genealogy Chat week of 27 Jan 2017 | Making the most of your conference experience](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3208/1006)
- What's on your bookshelf? | week of 20 Jan 2017
- How to Write a Good Question week of 13 Jan 2017
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 6 Jan 2017
- Genealogy Chat New Genealogy Toys | week of 30 December 2016
- WinterBash 2016: the Quest for Hats | week of 23 December 2016
- Editing Challenge: Making questions and answers more shareable | week of 16 Dec 2016
- Evaluating Websites | week of 9 Dec 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 2 Dec 2016
- Doing research in newspapers | week of 25 Nov 2016
- [Weekly Chat: using 'born digital' databases and index-only databases | week of 18 Nov 2016](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3177/1006)
- [Weekly Topic challenge: correlating military service records with other sources?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3176/1006) | week of 11 Nov 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 4 Nov 2016
- Understanding Archives | week of 28 Oct 2016
- The Perils of Using Online Trees for your research | week of 21 Oct 2016
- Using time and place to focus your research | week of 14 Oct 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 7 Oct 2016
- Using Finding Aids | week of 30 Sep 2016
- Finding information in unexpected places | week of 23 Sep 2016
- Effective use of Social Networking | week of 16 Sep 2016
- Keeping a Research Journal | week of 9 Sep 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 2 Sep 2016
- Genealogy Education and how it helped my research | week of 28 Aug 2016
- Blast from the past: ephemera and other sources not of an official nature (was 10/12/2013) | week of 19 Aug 2016
- Blast from the past: Genealogy Software (was week of 8/10/2013) | week of 12 Aug 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 5 August  2016
- [Weekly Chat: Turning the model upside down | week of 29 July 2016](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3162/1006) | week of 29 July 2016
- [What makes a question (and its answers) worth sharing?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3148/1006) | week of 22 July 2016
- DNA research: The Good, the Bad, the Ugly | week of 15 July 2016
- [Weekly Chat / Challenge: Have you reviewed your research lately?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3159/1006) | week of 8 July 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 1 July 2016
- Your favorite questions and answers on G&FH.SE | week of 24 July 2016
- Using maps in your research | week of 17 Jun 2016
- What I learned at the [2016 Southern California Genealogical Society Jamboree](http://genealogyjamboree.com/) | week of 10 Jun 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 3 Jun 2016
- Finding the right question to break down your brick wall | week of 27 Jun 2016
- [Weekly Chat: Finding hidden records | week of 20 May 2016](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2133/1006)
- Organizing your DNA Research | week of 13 May 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 6 May 2016
- Searching OCRed texts | week of 29 Apr 2016
- Writing Proof Statements | week of 22 Apr 2016
- Using Land Records for your Research | week of 15 Apr 2016
- Reviewing Your Prior Research | week of 8 Apr 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) | week of 1 Apr 2016
- Finding and analyzing Church Records in the United States | week of 25 Mar 2016
- Keeping organized week of 18 Mar 2016
- Genealogy Education week of 11 Mar 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 4 Mar 2016
- Improving the Weekly Chat, 2016 edition -- week of 26 Feb 2016
- Using non-genealogy software for your genealogy work -- week of 19 Feb 2016
- What I learned at RootsTech week of 12 Feb 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 5 Feb 2016
- Starting a Research Plan week of 29 Jan 2016
- How to Write a Good Answer week of 22 Jan 2016
- How to Write a Good Question week of 15 Jan 2016
- Working with Indirect Evidence week of 8 Jan 2016
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 1 Jan 2016
- [Genealogy Chat week of 25 December 2015 | New Genealogy Toys?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2115/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 18 December 2015 | Location, Location, Location](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2112/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 11 December 2015 | Data migration and transitioning to new genealogy software](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2111/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 4 December 2015
- [Genealogy Chat week of 27 November 2015 | Searching Ancestry: The Good, The Bad, The Ugly](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2104/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 20 November 2015 | New Ancestry: The Good, The Bad, The Ugly](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2103/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 13 November 2015 | Finding and analyzing military records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2102/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 6 November 2015 | Workshop on searching the 1939 Register](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2100/1006)
- [Topic challenge: Making effective use of burial and cemetery records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2097/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 30 October 2015 | Tales from the graveyard](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2099/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 23 October 2015 | Using archives and libraries for your family history research](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2093/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 16 October 2015 | Getting a clue -- mining documents for pointers to other research](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2092/1006)
- [Topic challenge: Need help with discovering Migration Patterns?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 9 Oct 2015 | Getting the most out of Electoral Registers](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2089/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 2 October 2015, as the Topic Challenge continues
- [Topic challenge: Need help with discovering Migration Patterns?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2077/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 18 Sep 2015 | Keeping up with the Joneses](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2072/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) weeks of 4 & 11  September, with a special focus on probate records, as the Topic Challenge continues
- [Weekly Topic Challenge: Finding and using Probate records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2071/1006) continues for the week of 28 Aug 2015
- [Weekly Topic Challenge: Finding and using Probate records](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2071/1006) week of 21 Aug 2015
- [Genealogy Chat week of 14 Aug 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: a soundly reasoned, coherently written conclusion](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2069/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 7 Aug 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: resolution of any conflicting evidence](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2068/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006)  week of 31 July 2015
- [Genealogy Chat week of 24th July 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: source citations](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2063/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 17th July 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: a reasonably exhaustive search](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2061/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat week of 10th July 2015 | The Genealogical Proof Standard: analysis of collected information](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2056/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006)  week of 3 July 2015
- Topic Challenge: [Is there a census record that you've looked and looked for but cannot find?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1921/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006)  week of 5 June 2015
- [Was your ancestor in a fraternal organization?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2015/1006)
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006)  week of 1 May 2015
- [Improving the weekly chat](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/1006)  week of 24 Apr 2015
- no topic suggested for week of 17 Apr 2015
- [Ask your ANZAC ancestry questions on 100th anniversary of Gallipoli landing!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2004/1006) week of 10 Apr 2015
- [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/1006) week of 3 Apr 2015
- For the first 13 weeks of 2015, we will follow along with Thomas MacEntee's Genealogy Do-Over: **[2015: Year (okay, thirteen weeks) of the Do-Over?](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1952/56)**

The Weekly Chat went on sabbatical for a while in late 2014 to make room for the Weekly Topic Challenge:

- **[WWI centenary and finding records about WWI service members](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1918/56)**
- **[Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/56)**

An overview and discussion of previous chat topics can be found here:

- **[Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56)**

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to revive the Monthly Workshop chat as described in [Genealogy Chat 1st week of Month | Monthly Workshop](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1893/56) for the first week of every month.

The idea behind the Workshop is for people to brainstorm about a problem they might be working on, so that they can clarify **which** research questions might be productive to ask.  It is not intended as a substitute for asking a question or answering one.

After the brainstorming session, if all goes well, it should be easier to write up a good question (and possibly to self-answer it).