# Weekly Chat | Genealogy Do-Over Week 1: 2-8 January 2015

Tags: discussion

To kick off our Weekly Chats for 2015, for the first 13 weeks, let's follow along with Thomas MacEntee's Genealogy Do-Over.

Thomas posted [Genealogy Do-Over – Week 1: 2-8 January 2015](http://www.geneabloggers.com/genealogy-doover-week-1-28-january-2015/) yesterday (1 January).

> Remember that while the Genealogy Do-Over is a project-based learning
>   initiative to improve genealogy research skills, you should be having
>   fun. You should look forward to trying new approaches each week.

Check out Thomas' post about:

1. Setting Previous Research Aside
2. Preparing to Research
3. Establishing Base Practices and Guidelines

If you don't want to set aside all your previous research, consider taking this as an opportunity to research someone close to your family, but not related by blood, like a favorite godparent or neighbor.

Are you participating in the Do-Over?  Want to talk about how your week is going?  Let's talk about improving our research skills.

The chat starts on Saturday, SE time, in the Genealogy Conference chat room, and runs for the entire week. You can [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder about when the topic changes over to the next week.