# Weekly Chat | Genealogy-Do Over Week 4: 23-29 January 2015

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

To kick off our Weekly Chats for 2015, for the first 13 weeks, let's follow along with Thomas MacEntee's [Genealogy Do-Over](http://www.geneabloggers.com/tag/genealogy-do-over/).

The topics for [Genealogy Do-Over – Week 4: 23-29 January 2015](http://www.geneabloggers.com/tag/genealogy-do-over/) are:

1. Managing Projects and Tasks
2. Tracking Searches

In his opening announcement about the Do-Over, Thomas said:

> Remember that while the Genealogy Do-Over is a project-based learning
>   initiative to improve genealogy research skills, you should be having
>   fun. You should look forward to trying new approaches each week.

If you don't want to set aside all your previous research, consider taking this as an opportunity to research someone close to your family, but not related by blood, like a favorite godparent or neighbor.  Thomas also has suggestions for doing a modified Do-Over -- a review of your prior research.

Are you participating in the Do-Over?  Want to talk about how your week is going?  Let's talk about improving our research skills.

The Weekly Chat starts on Saturday midnight, Stack Exchange time, in the Genealogy Conference chat room, and runs for the entire week. Here's a handy [time converter](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html) so you can find the start time in your timezone.

Midnight GMT is 4:00 PM Pacific Time on Friday, and I try to pop into the Conference Room at some point on (my) Friday afternoon to get the ball rolling.  If no one is in the room, feel free to leave a post about the week's topic for others to see.

You can [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder about when the topic changes over to the next week.