# Genealogy Chat week of 18 Sep 2015 | Keeping up with the Joneses

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

How do you keep up with the new record releases from your favorite websites?  And how do you incorporate the 'new' collections into your research plans?  Share your tips and techniques.

---

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get a reminder.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!