# Genealogy Chat week of 9 Oct 2015 | Getting the most out of Electoral Registers

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Electoral Registers -- lists of voters -- can be a fantastic resource for filling in gaps in your family's timeline.  But they can be a challenge to find and to work with.

How do you find them?  What research guides have been helpful? How do you organize the information you find.

Share your tips and techniques by posting a self-answered question, or talking about them in the Conference Room this week.

---

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!