# Genealogy Chat week of 16 October 2015 | Getting a clue -- mining documents for pointers to other research

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

As a follow-up to FamilySearch's [United States Research Seminar](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/United_States_Research_Seminar) which concluded today, our topic this week picks up from the final lecture, "Some People Really Need to Get a Clue! Document Analyzation and Evaluation".

Let's talk about how we can get the most out of the material we've already collected. What clues to other records are sitting right under our nose?  If you made a great find and smacked yourself, saying "Why didn't I see that before?", head over to the [Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference) and share your war stories there.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-conference) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!