# Genealogy Chat week of 23 October 2015 | Using archives and libraries for your family history research

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Have you tried searching for your focus person by name, and come up empty?  You've hit all your usual haunts, and don't know what do to next?

A wealth of material is waiting for the researcher who knows how to search a catalog. Are you hooked on [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/)? Does [ArchiveGrid](https://beta.worldcat.org/archivegrid/) make your day? Are you a [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) maven?  Is [TNA's Discovery](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/), [The NRS Catalog](http://nationalrecordsofscotland.gov.uk/research/catalogues-and-indexes), [National Archives of Australia](http://www.naa.gov.au/collection/search/) or [NARA's new catalog](https://www.archives.gov/research/catalog/) your go-to resource?

Come chat about your favorite online library and archive catalogs, share search tips, and talk about what finds you've made.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!

Comment: I think it would be worth adding links to those four catalogs.  I have to admit that I think they are a source that I am largely overlooking.

Comment: @PolyGeo what Australian archives should be added to this question?

Comment: I added a link to the National Archives of Australia.  They seem mainly to have military service records.