# Genealogy Chat week of 30 October 2015 | Tales from the graveyard

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Do you have a story to tell about tracking down the final resting place of your family members?  Come chat with us and talk about what finds you've made (and the misadventures you may have had while getting there).

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!