# Genealogy Chat week of 6 November 2015 | Workshop on searching the 1939 Register

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Let's chat about the hot topic of the month: the release of the long-awaited 1939 Register.  Share your search tips and triangulation strategies -- and if you've unlocked any of the records, talk about what you've found.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!