# Genealogy Chat week of 13 November 2015 | Finding and analyzing military records

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat, challenge

Remembrance Day / Veterans' Day was this week.  Did you find any new information about the service members in your family?  Do you need help finding or interpreting something in their records?

Come chat about it in the Conference Room -- share your stories! And if you have research tips to share or a puzzler you just can't solve, write up a question for the main site.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!