# Genealogy Chat week of 20 November 2015 | New Ancestry: The Good, The Bad, The Ugly

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Earlier this year, Ancestry introduced "New Ancestry" as a beta.  Now they have announced that the new look-and-feel will become permanent on 14 (Australia) and 15 (United States) December.  Have you used the new system yet?  After months of tweaking, is it finally ready for Prime Time?

Come chat about it in the Conference Room -- and share your experience.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!