# Genealogy Chat week of 27 November 2015 | Searching Ancestry: The Good, The Bad, The Ugly

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

Following up on last week's chat topic [New Ancestry: The Good, The Bad, The Ugly](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/genealogy-chat-week-of-20-november-2015-new-ancestry-the-good-the-bad-the-u), let's talk about the main areas of the site.  Some of the new record collections, like the recently-added collections in the [Wills, Probates, Land, Tax & Criminal](http://search.ancestry.com/search/cardcatalog.aspx#ccat=hc=25&dbSort=1&sbo=1&title=wills&keyword=&filter=0*36&) category, are only accessible to users who are using the new site.

Have you had difficulty searching, especially in these new collections?  What problems have you had? What workarounds have you discovered?

Come chat about it in the Conference Room -- ask questions, share your experiences.  And if you solve a problem or make a new discovery because of the chat, don't forget to write up what you learned in a self-answered question.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!