# Genealogy Chat week of 11 December 2015 | Data migration and transitioning to new genealogy software

Tags: discussion, weekly-genealogy-chat

This week Ancestry.com announced that its desktop software Family Tree Maker will no longer be sold as of 31 December 2015, and that support will end after a year (1 January 2017).

Let's talk about what we need to consider when choosing new genealogy software, and other strategies for future-proofing our digital genealogy 'holdings'.

Come chat about it in the Conference Room -- ask questions, share your experiences.  And if you solve a problem or make a new discovery because of the chat, don't forget to write up what you learned in a self-answered question.

The chat will occur in [The Conference Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat) all week long. Be sure to [register yourself](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9987/genealogy-weekly-chat?tab=schedule) to get an alert each week.

If you have any ideas for future topics, post them as answers to [Weekly genealogy chat topics - now a week long event!](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1750/56) and they might be used in an upcoming week!